# Can anyone explain why this unit test is failing?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

This has stumped a few of us. It's VS2013, and the code itself builds correctly as you can see from the image. We've run this test on 2 different machines with the same results.

I did copy/paste the code originally into and from MS OneNote, so possibly there is a reason there. But as you can see from Notepad++ there don't appear to be any special characters.

Ideas?

[image]

[image]

To expand on this, the following version also fails:

```
    //Note: Why this does not pass is baffling
    [TestMethod]
    public void FunnyTestThatFailsForSomeReason()
    {
        const string expectedErrorMessage = "Web Session Not Found.";

        var a = "Web Session Not Found.";
        string b = "Web Session Not Found.";

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedErrorMessage, a);
        //Assert.AreEqual(expectedErrorMessage, b);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedErrorMessage.ToString(), b.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Probably comparing reference equality. There's usually a `StringAssert` class for this. (I just checked, [you probably want this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243448.aspx).)

Comment: What does the exception message say?

Comment: @mclaassen, Additional information: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Web Session Not Found.>. Actual:<Web Session Not Found.>.

Comment: So far the only thing that makes it pass is to actually retype (with the keyboard) the line: b = "Web Session Not Found.";

Comment: @BenPower Look closely at the Notepad++ text: the whitespace between the words is different between `a` and `b` (with the former matching that shown in `expectedErrorMessage`). I don't know what characters are in `a` and `expectedErrorMessage`, but it doesn't look like they're plain ASCII space characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [`Assert.AreEqual(Object, Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243413.aspx) which (in this case) is looking for reference equality. [It's not going to work the way you want it to](http://ideone.com/XpGvEs).

> Verifies that two specified objects are equal. The assertion fails if the objects are not equal.

Use [`Assert.AreEqual(String, String, Boolean)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243448.aspx).

> Verifies that two specified strings are equal, ignoring case or not as specified. The assertion fails if they are not equal.

Or, more simply, your strings *are* subtly different. Copy and pasting appears to have yielded different results:

[image: Chrome]

Comment: As to why it works for the first case and not the second, there's some information about that [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty.aspx).

Comment: Assert.AreEqual(expectedErrorMessage, b, true); causes the same error: 
Additional information: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Web Session Not Found.>. Actual:<Web Session Not Found.>.

Comment: Also, I've type them all as strings and it exhibits the same behaviour. See above edits.

Comment: Try copying and pasting it into notepad and doing file => save => ansi encoding (or ASCII or whatever it is). If you get a warning while saving you probably have some character you're not expecting.

Comment: indeed that has solved the mystery. Thanks!

            const string expectedErrorMessage = "WebÂ SessionÂ NotÂ Found.";

            var a = "WebÂ SessionÂ NotÂ Found.";
            string b = "Web Session Not Found.";

Answer (score 0):

(Here for formatting purposes; the existing answer also explains what's happened. This is just the hex dump of your question's code.)

```
00000000:  2020 2020 7661 7220 6120 3d20 2257 6562 c2a0 5365 7373 696f  :    var a = "Web..Sessio
00000018:  6ec2 a04e 6f74 c2a0 466f 756e 642e 223b 0a20 2020 2020 2020  :n..Not..Found.";.       
00000030:  2020 2020 2073 7472 696e 6720 6220 3d20 2257 6562 2053 6573  :     string b = "Web Ses
00000048:  7369 6f6e 204e 6f74 2046 6f75 6e64 2e22 3b0a                 :sion Not Found.";.
```

The strings aren't the same.